# Spring Form Taglib Checkboxes and the Default Value

Tags: spring-mvc, checkbox, taglib

I am trying to display a list of checkboxes based on a list of data that I have.  I have managed to do this, however, I don't seem to be able to set the checked values for the required items.

If I have the following class structure.

```
public class Basic {
    private String name;
    private List<CBItem> cbItems;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<CBItem> getCbItems() {
        return cbItems;
    }

    public void setCbItems(List<CBItem> cbItems) {
        this.cbItems = cbItems;
    }
}

public class CBItem {
    private String name;
    private Boolean selected;

    public CBItem(String name, Boolean selected) {
        this.name = name;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Boolean getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

I am initialising it like this in my controller:

```
public String handleDemo(Model model) {
    Basic basic = new Basic();

    basic.setName("Basic Data Structure");

    List<CBItem> cbItems = new ArrayList<CBItem>();
    cbItems.add(new CBItem("First", true));
    cbItems.add(new CBItem("Second",false));
    cbItems.add(new CBItem("Third", false));
    cbItems.add(new CBItem("Fourth", true));
    basic.setCbItems(cbItems);

    model.addAttribute("basic", basic);
    return "demo";
}
```

and displaying it on the jsp page using this statement:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Basic Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <sf:form modelAttribute="basic">
        <sf:checkboxes path="cbItems" items="${basic.cbItems}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="selected" delimiter="<br/>" />
    </sf:form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I checked the Spring documentation for the checkbox tag:

> There are 3 approaches to the checkbox tag which should meet all your
>   checkbox needs.
>
> Approach One - When the bound value is of type java.lang.Boolean, 
>   the input(checkbox) is marked as 'checked' if the
>   bound value is true. The value attribute corresponds to the resolved
>   value of the setValue(Object) value property.
>
> Approach Two - When the
>   bound value is of type array or java.util.Collection, the
>   input(checkbox) is marked as 'checked' if the configured
>   setValue(Object) value is present in the bound Collection.
>
> Approach
>   Three - For any other bound value type, the input(checkbox) is marked
>   as 'checked' if the configured setValue(Object) is equal to the bound
>   value.

I am lead to believe that as the bound value in itemValue="selected" binds the value to a Boolean then the value of the boolean should add the checked statement for those values where selected = Boolean.TRUE.  However, using Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE I am getting the following generated HTML

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Testing Basic Data</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form id="basic" action="/demo" method="post"> 
        <span>
            <input id="cbItems1" name="cbItems" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="cbItems1">First</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <br/>
            <input id="cbItems2" name="cbItems" type="checkbox" value="false" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="cbItems2">Second</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <br/>
            <input id="cbItems3" name="cbItems" type="checkbox" value="false" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="cbItems3">Third</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <br/>
            <input id="cbItems4" name="cbItems" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="cbItems4">Fourth</label>
        </span>
        <input type="hidden" name="_cbItems" value="on"/> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Where the value is being set to true or false, rather than correctly adding the checked attribute.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit off I'm afraid. Lets have a look at your checkboxes tag.

`<sf:checkboxes path="cbItems" items="${basic.cbItems}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="selected" delimiter="<br/>" />`

It binds to `basic.cbItems` which is fine. But as the `items` attribute you provide the exact same list. Since both are equal all checkboxes will be selected no matter what `itemValue` you provide. Instead, you should provide a collection with all possible values to `items`. You should also override `hashCode()` and `equals()` for the `CBItem` class so instances can be tested for equality. After doing so your code will look like e.g.

#### Handler method

```
public String demo(ModelMap model) {
    Basic basic = new Basic();

    basic.setName("Basic Data Structure");

    List<CBItem> allItems = new ArrayList<CBItem>();
    allItems.add(new CBItem("First", true));
    allItems.add(new CBItem("Second",false));
    allItems.add(new CBItem("Third", false));
    allItems.add(new CBItem("Fourth", true));

    model.addAttribute("allItems", allItems);

    List<CBItem> cbItems = new ArrayList<>();
    cbItems.add(new CBItem("First", true));
    cbItems.add(new CBItem("Third", true));
    basic.setCbItems(cbItems);

    model.addAttribute("basic", basic);

    return "demo";
}
```

#### JSP form tag

```
<sf:form modelAttribute="basic">
    <sf:checkboxes path="cbItems" items="${allItems}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="name" delimiter="<br/>" />
</sf:form>
```